# Apollo-server password.js authentication

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm new to node.js GraphQL apollo-server, and for the first time I use password.js.I need to do authentication using passport.js.my token should border is stored in cooks.I am tormented for 7 days to do this.please, who can explain to me how should I do all this using Apollo-server password.js ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unanswered within the community as there is so many ways to do authentication with graphQL. Here is a 1 arbitrary example to get you on your way.

**Context** - The function is executed on each request to your graphQL server.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    context: ({ req }) => {
        try {
            const authToken = req.header["Auth-token"];

            const user = passport.authenticate("local", authToken);

            return { user };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);

            return {};
        }
    }
});
```

Whatever is returned from the  **Context** function is available inside your resolvers as the third argument.

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        getUserCheese: (root, args, context) => {
            return findCheeseByUserName(context.user.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that 10 people watched my question

Comment: @Jesus, hello, when I say "unanswered within the community" I don't mean, StackOverflow. I mean the whole graphql community, authentication within graphql has no definite go-to answer. But I hope my example gets you on the right track.

Comment: hello .I know that there are many ways.I need a full-fledged working example , which I just can't find.I want to thank you for the answer, but your example didnt help me much.as I said I need to add a token to cookie.then I have to accept cookies, take a token from it and do a user check.I have no idea how I should do this with apollo-server password.js